# Prevent Adobe Acrobat from setting as default PDF reader automatically

Tags: windows, pdf, adobe-acrobat

I have the problem that, as soon as I open one document with Adobe Acrobat, it sets itself as default PDF reader. If I use right click-> open with -> Adobe Acrobat, I do not click the check box for setting the app ad default app. Even if I open a pdf from another program, e.g. outlook, Acrobat sets itself as default reader.

SumatraPDF is set as the system's default application for `.pdf` files.

If I open a pdf once with Adobe Acrobat, also the default system application changes from SumatraPDF to Adobe Acrobat even though I do not select any checkbox which says that it should update the default app.

Does anyone know how to prevent this behaviour?

Comment: I know but I do not choose Adobe Acrobat to be the default app, it sets itself as default app once I open one single document with Adobe Acrobat.

Comment: Sumatra pdf is set as default app. Sorry for the confusion, I only have Adobe Acrobat installed.

Comment: I added the answer to my initial question.

Comment: And I deleted yet another unnecessary comment :-)